# Jquery new line after press enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add a new line after press enter. My code can add only 1 time. Please, help.

```js
$(function () {
  $('.items:last .item-quantity').keypress(function(e) {
    var keyCode, path, duplicate;

    keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(keyCode == '13') {
      path = '.items:last';
      duplicate = $(path).clone();
      duplicate.children().val(null);
      $(path).after(duplicate);
      $(path + ' .item-name').focus();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 items">
  <input type="text" class="form-control item-name col-xs-2" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="text" class="form-control item-quantity col-xs-2" placeholder="Quantity">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are only attaching the `keypress` event listener to the last `input` element when the page loads. You could [delegate the event](http://api.jquery.com/on/) handler to a common ancestor element in order to listen to the event on the newly appended elements:

```js
$(document).on('keypress', '.items:last .item-quantity', function(event) {
  var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
  var path = '.items:last';
  var $duplicate = $(path).clone();

  if (keyCode === 13) {
    $duplicate.children().val('');
    $(path).after($duplicate);
    $('.item-name', path).focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 items">
  <input type="text" class="form-control item-name col-xs-2" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="text" class="form-control item-quantity col-xs-2" placeholder="Quantity">
</div>
```

In the snippet above, the event listener is delegated to the `document` object. This means that a check is made for all the `keypress` events that propagate up the `document` object. Therefore it would be more efficient if you can attach the event listener directly to to a common ancestor.

For instance:

```js
$('.parent-container').on('keypress', '.items:last .item-quantity', function(event) {
  var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
  var path = '.items:last';
  var $duplicate = $(path).clone();

  if (keyCode === 13) {
    $duplicate.find('input').val('');
    $(path).after($duplicate);
    $('.item-name', path).focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 items">
    <input type="text" class="form-control item-name col-xs-2" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" class="form-control item-quantity col-xs-2" placeholder="Quantity">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the `focus()`?

```js
$(function () {
  $('.items:last .item-quantity').keypress(function(e) {
    var keyCode, path, duplicate;

    keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(keyCode == '13') {
      path = '.items:last';
      duplicate = $(path).clone();
      duplicate.children().val(null);
      $(path).after(duplicate);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 items">
  <input type="text" class="form-control item-name col-xs-2" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="text" class="form-control item-quantity col-xs-2" placeholder="Quantity">
</div>
```